# Resource temporarily unavailable Error while reading row groups of Parquet file using PyArrow in MPI4PY environment

Tags: python-3.x, mpi, parquet, pyarrow, mpi4py

I have a parquet file with 6 row groups. I am able to read the 6 row groups using the first 6 (`0-5`) processes (ranks). But when the process (rank) #6 and onwards  try to read the row groups again another round it throws errors.

I read a row group of `file_name` as the following:

```
  idx = convert_rank_to_idx(rank)
  parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile(file_name)
  rowgroup = parquet_file.read_row_group(idx)
```

The `convert_rank_to_idx(rank)` converts the rank number to row group indices (i.e. 0 to 5). For example, rank 6 should read row group zero again (which already is read once by rank 0) and rank 7 row group one (which already is read once by rank 1) and so on.

This is the error:

```
  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Resource temporarily unavailable
      *** Process received signal ***
  Signal: Aborted (6)
  Signal code:  (-6)
  [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x10c10)[0x7f9e58dd0c10]
  [ 1] /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7f9e58a4ff67]
  [ 2] /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x13a)[0x7f9e58a5133a]
  [ 3] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/_libs/window/../../../../../libstdc++.so.6(_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0xbc)[0x7f9e28ee684a]
  [ 4] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/_libs/window/../../../../../libstdc++.so.6(+0xabf47)[0x7f9e28ee4f47]
  [ 5] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/_libs/window/../../../../../libstdc++.so.6(+0xabf7d)[0x7f9e28ee4f7d]
  [ 6] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/_libs/window/../../../../../libstdc++.so.6(__cxa_rethrow+0x0)[0x7f9e28ee515a]
  [ 7] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/_libs/window/../../../../../libstdc++.so.6(_ZSt20__throw_system_errori+0x74)[0x7f9e28ee22f3]
  [ 8] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/_libs/window/../../../../../libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_6_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvvE+0x20)[0x7f9e28f0133a]
  [ 9] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/../../../libarrow.so.200(_ZN5arrow8internal10ThreadPool21LaunchWorkersUnlockedEi+0xc3)[0x7f9e27d00653]
  [10] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/../../../libarrow.so.200(_ZN5arrow8internal10ThreadPool11SetCapacityEi+0x263)[0x7f9e27d01073]
  [11] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/../../../libarrow.so.200(_ZN5arrow8internal10ThreadPool4MakeEi+0x256)[0x7f9e27d01de6]
  [12] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/../../../libarrow.so.200(_ZN5arrow8internal10ThreadPool11MakeEternalEi+0x34)[0x7f9e27d02514]
  [13] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/../../../libarrow.so.200(_ZN5arrow8internal10ThreadPool17MakeCpuThreadPoolEv+0x31)[0x7f9e27d03cf1]
  [14] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/../../../libarrow.so.200(_ZN5arrow8internal16GetCpuThreadPoolEv+0x5d)[0x7f9e27d03f9d]
  [15] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/../../../libarrow_python.so.200(_ZN5arrow2py20ConvertTableToPandasERKNS0_13PandasOptionsESt10shared_ptrINS_5TableEEPP7_object+0xd9e)[0x7f9e27818b0e]
  [16] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/lib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x1cb846)[0x7f9e286e8846]
  [17] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/lib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x1cc0d9)[0x7f9e286e90d9]
  [18] python(_PyCFunction_FastCallDict+0x154)[0x4303edbed4]
  [19] python(+0x199afc)[0x4303f63afc]
  [20] python(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x30a)[0x4303f862ca]
  [21] python(+0x1930ce)[0x4303f5d0ce]
  [22] python(+0x193c61)[0x4303f5dc61]
  [23] python(+0x199bd5)[0x4303f63bd5]
  [24] python(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x30a)[0x4303f862ca]
  [25] python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x329)[0x4303f5e779]
  [26] python(+0x1956a6)[0x4303f5f6a6]
  [27] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/lib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x93ec6)[0x7f9e285b0ec6]
  [28] /home/mrezaeif/.conda/envs/fast-mpi4py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/lib.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x11645f)[0x7f9e2863345f]
  [29] python(PyCFunction_Call+0xc6)[0x4303edef06]
         *** End of error message ***
```

I was wondering if anyone has encountered this issue before, or may have some suggestions or a solution. Is there some blocking happening inside Pyarrow read function?